# How to Play Youtube Videos In Windows phone 8 application? and make application Resolution compatible

Tags: c#-4.0

Hello I am developing a windows phone 8 application. My application is complete i am left with two things
first, i have to play videos from youtube channel.
second, i have to make application resolution compatible.

I visited so many pages but no luck.

can someone help me out, My deadline for application submission is near.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to say that I have not checked the example, but at least the details on the page suggest that you an use it for playing you tube videos: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Youtube-Video-Sample-f2692dc9

---

Comment: Yes Sir, i already went thru that. But it is not working in my case. I tried exact code, but it is giving me error. i am deserializing Json and in that json data i am having youtube video_code something like this. www./\youtube.\/\/.com/video, using this video_code i have to play videos.

Comment: UPDATE: I made my app resolution compatible. All i am left with is playing videos.

Comment: Ok, heres other link to parsing the youtube responce: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_parse_YouTube_API_response also code for using mediaelement included in it

Comment: Sir i tried that too. But when i am passing video_code like this www./\youtube.\/\/.com/video to media player task gives me Error and displays this message in message box. "Sorry, we can't play this file on your phone."

Comment: namespace youtube
{
    public partial class playvideo : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string video_code = "";
        public playvideo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += play_youtube_video;
        }}

     public void play_youtube_video(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)     {         
 NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("video_code", out video_code);
YouTube.Play(video_code, true, YouTubeQuality.Quality720P, (ex) = {if (ex != null) { SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }}); } } }

Comment: First of all sorry sir, for writing code above like that,  i was running out of words limit, that's why it is like that. So i am doing that way and it returns me message box with this error "The remote server returned an error NotFound.

Comment: Then I suggest you have a close look into your code, and see what goes wrong with the parsing. The Not Found error sounds to me that you are trying to access something that is not there, and could indeed be that you are using incorrect or partial ID.

Comment: Sir still no luck with that. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Sir can you explain with a snippet, how can i parse this video_code youtube.com/v/Rngoby7Vu28 THIS IS EXACT video_code in my API(JSON).

Answer (score 1):

You should add [MyToolkit.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit.Extended/) package from NuGet.

```
try
{
    var videoUri = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(
        "uRs4hz1YEQc", MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.QualityMedium);

    MediaYouTubeVideo.Source = videoUri.Uri;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
   // TODO: Show error
}
```

Comment: I tried this and my uri is always null :( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEuJm-0RmBM